# Strange Python boolean operator

Tags: python, python-2.x

I saw some variations of the following simple piece of code:

```
if dist_1>dist_2 :
    print enemy_2
else:
    print enemy_1
```

Variation 1:

```
print (enemy_1, enemy_2)[dist_1 > dist_2]
```

Variation 2:

```
e1, d1, e2 = (raw_input() for _ in '123')
print (e1, e2)[d1 > raw_input()]
```

Can someone please explain how this `print (x,y)[x>y]` code works?

Comment: I added a python 2 tag here because I am pretty sure this would not work in Python 3

Comment: It's just a tuple and accesses either 0 or 1 based on the outcome of `x > y`...

Comment: @MadPhysicist it took no time to test this under 3.6.0. It works!

Comment: It works because True is converted to 1 and False to 0. But I'd prefer:`print (e1 if d1 > raw_input () else e2)`

Comment: @JacquesdeHooge, is it converted automatically or is there any cast, I provided an answer, but I got downvoted since it seems True is 1 and False is 0.

Comment: @lmiguelvargasf: Automatically. And don't bother being downvoted. I get downvoted all the time. You need a thick skin to attempt to help someone...

Comment: @Jules: [No it doesn't](http://ideone.com/pQBg0Y), because it's using Python 2 `print` syntax.

Comment: @Jules. I don't believe you. `e1, e2, d1, d2 = 'a', 'b', 1, 2; print (e1, e2)[d1 > d2]` raises a `TypeError: 'NoneType' is not subscriptable` error as expected. The parens are now function argument delimiters, not tuple delimiters.

Comment: Can you select an answer once your question has been closed?

Comment: @MadPhysicist my mistake, I'd used the expression so that it's not in a function invocation (only at the top level of the REPL). Your re-tag is appropriate.

Comment: What an enormous nonsense to downvote this question, or label it off-topic. I think OP just shows he's willing to take the trouble to look it up. But the answer is far from trivial, and certainly isn't easy to find in a book if you're not a Python expert.

Comment: @JacquesdeHooge. I will edit this not to be a request for off-site documentation and we can get this thing reopened.

Comment: Thank you all for your time. 
Apparently it was an easy answer. It never crossed my mind that the boolean was an index. It was so obvious, yet i didn't see it.

However I dont think the question was off-topic at all.

thank you all, once again for your time and knowledge.

Comment: @MadPhysicist Yes . making it non-offtopic would be a good idea as many new programmers coould become unstuck by the answer, thus saving time for themselves and also for the stack overflow community.

Comment: @JacquesdeHooge. Feel free to second my reopen vote.

Comment: @MadPhysicist Done

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Booleans are actually a subclass of integers in Python:

```
isinstance(True, int)
isinstance(False, int)
```

are both true statements. So you can index a two-element sequence with a boolean. If the boolean is `False`, you will get the first element. If the boolean is `True`, you will get the second element.

The expression `(enemy_1, enemy_2)` creates a two-element `tuple`. `[dist_1 > dist_2]` provides the boolean index. The `print` is incidental; it is just used to output the result.

Comment: To prevent confusion: type bool is derived from type int, so isinstance (2, bool) is False. So indeed bools are integers, but integers are not bools. Like a cat is an animal, but an animal isn't necessarily a cat.

Comment: @JacquesdeHooge. I don't thing it's especially relevant that the converse is not true, but I did make my language more precise to indicate it.

Comment: I'd love to know why the downvote. Is something untrue or fundamentally lacking in my explanation?

Comment: Your language was concise enough. It was just a clarification. In daily language when people say 'is' they think of it as 'equals', rather than 'is a '. BTW, nothing lacking in your answer, just some funny people downvoting everything...

Answer (score 1):

If you put some element(s) in parens with at least one comma it becomes a tuple. Similar to a list, you can index a tuple. You index using integers, usually. However, if you index using a boolean then False will be interpreted as 0 and True will be interpreted as 1.

So the code:

```
(enemy_1, enemy_2)[dist_1 > dist_2]
```

Is interpreted in English as "if dist_1 > than dist_2 give me item 1 from the tuple, else give me item 0."

If you want, you can do a tuple tutorial.

Comment: "If you put something in parens it becomes a tuple". Not necessarily: is `(2)` a tuple?

Comment: @Jean-FrançoisFabre Notpick: If it's part of a function call then yes, it could become part of a tuple ([`PyArg_ParseTupleAndKeywords`](https://docs.python.org/3/c-api/arg.html#c.PyArg_ParseTupleAndKeywords) or if the function accepts `*args`) :-)